# MRU List when Inserting/Update record from APEX trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, api, dml

Can we set an option when inserting record via APEX Trigger that the record "does not" show up in Salesforce MRU (Recent items list) ?

Comment: According to the docs, that feature (to not update the MRU) doesn't appear to be surfaced in Apex in the same way it is in the APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

However you are not the first person with this problem. There is an [idea](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YWdWAAW) on the idea exchange requesting the same access. The best you can do right now is vote for it and hope Salesforce addresses the idea.

Comment: Thats sad. I can see that there is an updateMRU header option accessible via API (as shown in there online documentation: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_header_mruheader.htm?SearchType=Stem) but don't have this option in APEX, very sad. Plus this IDEA is an year old and I dont think they would by any chance include it in any immediate release :( ...